# Build pipeline migration from circleci to vsts

Tags: azure-devops, circleci

Does anybody know how to migrate build pipelines from circleci to VSTS?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the time to go through stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t the official tool to migrate build pipeline from circleci to VSTS, but there are the REST APIs (e.g. [Build definitions](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions)) that you can create new build definitions per to circleci (e.g. circle.yml) programmatically, so you can build a tool to migrate circleci to VSTS through REST API by yourselves.